# 固定したハッシュ値を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

RubyのHash値取得に関する質問です．
下記のコードにおいて，実行毎に変化しないハッシュ値を取得したいのですが，どのように対処すればよいのでしょうか．
ご教授お願い致します．

```
# ハッシュ値を取得してある値を計算するテストコード
require 'test/unit'
require 'cmath'

# 引数のハッシュ値に基づく乱数生成器を設定する
def uniqueRandom(*args)
  sumHash = 0
  args.each{ |i|
    p i.to_s + "のHash値" + i.hash.to_s
    sumHash = sumHash + i.hash
  }
  rnd = Random.new(sumHash)
  return rnd
end

class UnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_getHashValue
    rnd = uniqueRandom(10, "Channel")
    p (1.0 / 17.4905) * CMath.exp(Complex(Math.cos(rnd.rand(1.0)), Math.sin(rnd.rand(1.0))) * 2 * Math::PI)
  end
end
```

Comment: MD5(Message Digest)を使うのはどうでしょう。`require 'digest/md5'` として、`args.each{ |i| p i.to_s + "のHash値" + i.hash.to_s; sumHash = sumHash + i.hash }` の部分を、`args.each{ |i| h = Digest::MD5.digest(i.to_s).unpack("Q!")[0]; p i.to_s + "のHash値" + h.to_s;sumHash = sumHash + h }` に置き換えます。

Comment: @metropolis さんのご提示頂いた方法で固定されたHash値を取得できました．ありがとうございます．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Zlib.#crc32](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/method/Zlib/m/crc32.html)が使うと文字列のみ依存で一定となるCRC-32の整数値(Integer)を返します。

```
require 'zlib'
str = 'hoge'
crc = Zlib.crc32(str)
p crc #=> 2335827034 (環境異存なし)
```

CRC-32の範囲は符号無し32bit整数値です。そのためRandomのシード値として使用した場合、たかだが2<sup>32</sup>しかパターンがありません。より多くのパターンを生成した場合はdigestモジュールを使用します。

```
str = 'hoge'

require 'digest/md5'
md5 = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 128bits
p md5 #=> 311622155487174517432991262857998412670

require 'digest/rmd160'
rmd160 = Digest::RMD160.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 160bits
p rmd160 #=> 421215687515797509955010976893163978158450862449

require 'digest/sha1'
sha1 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 160bits
p sha1 #=> 285160836105145057295564030126526459180476620348

require 'digest/sha2'
sha256 = Digest::SHA256.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 256bits
sha384 = Digest::SHA384.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 384bits
sha512 = Digest::SHA512.hexdigest(str).to_i(16) # 512bits
p sha256 #=> 1070681082186409...5136609985194021
p sha384 #=> 3142410166718590...8678657356121888
p sha512 #=> 1150699269346398...6863431099807449
```

いずれの値も環境に依存せずに文字列によって常に同じになります。

なお、CRC-32は値から元の文字列を推測できる場合がありますので、セッション値生成などセキュリティーに関わる部分には使用しないでください。ダイジェスト関数であってもMD5やSHA1は脆弱性が発見されていますので、ビット数に応じた強度を持つとは考えないでください。(そもそも、セキュリティに関わる部分にRandomは使用すべきではなく、SecureRandomを使用すべきですが)

Comment: 非常に詳しく教えていただきありがとうございます．
digestを使うことでできました．